# Filter pandas Data Frame Based on other Dataframe Column Values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

df1:

```
Id   Country  Product
1    india    cotton
2    germany  shoes
3    algeria  bags
```

df2:

```
id   Country  Product  Qty   Sales
1    India    cotton   25    635
2    India    cotton   65    335
3    India    cotton   96    455
4    India    cotton   78    255
5    germany  shoes    25    635
6    germany  shoes    65    458
7    germany  shoes    96    455
8    germany  shoes    69    255
9    algeria  bags     25    635
10   algeria  bags     89    788
11   algeria  bags     96    455
12   algeria  bags     78    165
```

I need to filter df2 based on the Country and Products Column from df1 and Create New Data Frame.
For example in df1, there are 3 unique country, Categories, so Number of df would be 3.

Output:

```
df_India_Cotton :

id   Country  Product  Qty   Sales
1    India    cotton   25    635
2    India    cotton   65    335
3    India    cotton   96    455
4    India    cotton   78    255

df_germany_Product:

id   Country  Product  Qty   Sales
1    germany  shoes    25    635
2    germany  shoes    65    458
3    germany  shoes    96    455
4    germany  shoes    69    255

df_algeria_Product:

id  Country  Product  Qty   Sales
1   algeria  bags     25    635
2   algeria  bags     89    788
3   algeria  bags     96    455
4   algeria  bags     78    165
```

i can also filter out these dataframe with basic subsetting in pandas.

```
df[(df.Country=='India') & (df.Products=='cotton')]
```

it would solve this problem, there could be so many unique combination of Country, Products in my df1.

Comment: Isn't it just groupby ?

Comment: why do you need to do this? what happens after you filter them?

Comment: @PaulH i just need different dataframes because after i have to send this dataframes to different location

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Be specific about you're trying to accomplish. Are you trying to write them all to files? Pass them to functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a dictionary and save all dataframes in it.
Check the code below:

```
d={}
for i in range(len(df1)):
    name=df1.Country.iloc[i]+'_'+df1.Product.iloc[i]
    d[name]=df2[(df2.Country==df1.Country.iloc[i]) & (df2.Product==df1.Product.iloc[i])]
```

And you can call each dataframe by its values like below:

d['India_cotton'] will give:

```
id   Country  Product  Qty   Sales
1    India    cotton   25    635
2    India    cotton   65    335
3    India    cotton   96    455
4    India    cotton   78    255
```

Comment: The answer 1) isn't indented properly and 2) will create a new dataframe for every *row* in the data frame, not every unique combination of Country and Product (though they are over written)

Comment: 1) Thanks i updated the code
2) It's supposed that combinations in df1 are unique. If they are not and there are performance issues, we can add a line to check the existing keys of the dictionary, or just work with the set of zipped columns of df1. TS let me know if you need any help with that

Comment: they're clearly not unique in in the OP's question. If they were, you'd be writing a single row to each element of the dictionary.

Comment: You are talking about df1 or df2?

Comment: ooooops -- i forgot about df1

Answer (score 0):

Try creating two groupby's. Use the first to select from the second:

```
import pandas as pd

selector_df = pd.DataFrame(data=
                           {
                               'Country':'india germany algeria'.split(),
                               'Product':'cotton shoes bags'.split()
                           })

details_df = pd.DataFrame(data=
                         {
                            'Country':'india india india india germany germany germany germany algeria algeria algeria algeria'.split(),
                            'Product':'cotton cotton cotton cotton shoes shoes shoes shoes bags bags bags bags'.split(),
                            'qty':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
                         })

selectorgroups = selector_df.groupby(by=['Country', 'Product'])
datagroups = details_df.groupby(by=['Country', 'Product'])
for tag, group in selectorgroups:
    print(tag)
    try:
        print(datagroups.get_group(tag))
    except KeyError:
        print('tag does not exist in datagroup')
```